# Map alternative

Tags: apex

I am looping Agent_Engagements__c list and use map of Agents to find right agent. This works OK :

```
 Map<String, Id> agentMap = new Map<String, Id>();

    for(Agent_Details__c eachAgent: agents){    
        string teamLang =  eachAgent.Team__c + eachAgent.Language__c;
        agentMap.put(teamLang, eachAgent.Agent__c);                     
    }

for(Agent_Engagements__c ae: aes){             
string aeteamLang = ae.Account__r.Country__r.Helpdesk_Region__c + ae.Account__r.Country__r.Language__c;        
          ae.Agent__c= agentMap.get(aeteamLang);            
      }       
        update aes;
```

I need to change so that when there is >1 agent with the same region/language in Agent_Details_c then Agent_Engagements__c are assigned equally between the number of found agents. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExcange. This site is not meant for providing you with ready-made solutions, but rather to help you continue where you got stuck. What did you try so far? What didn't work about it? For some tips, you can check this page: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a nested collection.

```
Map<String, List<Id>> agentsByLang = new Map<String, List<Id>>();
for(Agent_Details__c agent: agents) {
  agentsByLang.put(agent.Team__c+agent.Language__c, new List<Id>());
}
for(Agent_Details__c agent: agents) {
  agentsByLang.get(agent.Team__c+agent.Language__c).add(agent.Agent__c);
}
for(Agent_Engagements__c engagement: engagements) {
  Country__c country = engagement.Account__r.Country__r;
  String key = country.Helpdesk_Region__c + country.Language__c);
  Id[] validAgents = agentsByLang.get(key);
  // Set Agent__c to first in list, move that Id to end of list
  validAgents.add(engagement.Agent__c = validAgents.remove(0));
}
```

This allows you to rotate between agents within the same transaction.